# Dynamically loading multiple <li>'s with a javascript for loop - nothing loading yet

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to load X amount of `<li>`'s into a `<ul>` via a `for` loop in a jquery function, and while I think I've got the syntax about right I'm not getting anything loading. (no problem with loading a single `<li>`, but none for multiples with the method I've tried)

Initially I attempted to pass a variable into the loop to determine the amount of increments: `var peekListAmount = 5;`

That didn't work so I went for a bog-standard loop incrementer. That doesn't work either so, after searching here and getting close, I have put together a fiddle to see if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/janowicz/hEjxP/8/

Ultimately I want to use Knockout.js to dynamically input a number to pass to the loop amount variable, but 1st things 1st.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: please paste your code here!

Comment: please show the relevant parts of your code here, in case the fiddle disappears.

Comment: @Maulik and Alnitak - apologies for no code here, and big thanks for your reply Alnitak, does the job perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
var peekListItem = $('<li>...</li>');
```

you're creating a *single* instance of an `<li>` node, encapsulated in a jQuery object.

Appending an already-present node to the DOM just removes it from its current place in the DOM tree, and moves it to the new place.

You need to create the node *inside* the loop, not outside, otherwise you're just re-appending the *same* node each time, not a copy of that node.

In fact, given you're not manipulating that node, you can just put the required HTML directly inside the `.append()` call without wrapping it in `$(...)` at all:

```
$(function() {
    var peekList = $('<ul class="peekaboo-list">').appendTo('div.peekaboo-wrap');

    function addLiAnchorNodes(nodeAmount) {
        var html = '<li><a href="#" class="peekaboo-link"></a>' +
                   '<p class="peekaboo-text"></p></li>';

        for (var i = 0; i < nodeAmount; ++i) {
            peekList.append(html);
        }
    }
    addLiAnchorNodes(5);
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/8xvbY/

Answer (score 1):

Here is you updated code

```
$(function(){
    var peekList = $('<ul class="peekaboo-list"></ul>');
    var peekListItem = '<li><a href="#" class="peekaboo-link"></a><p class="peekaboo-text"></p></li>';
    //var peekListAmount = 5;   
    var tmp = '';
    var addLiAnchorNodes = function (nodeAmount){
        //var nodeAmount = peekListAmount;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            tmp += peekListItem;
        }
        peekList.append(tmp);
         $('div.peekaboo-wrap').append(peekList); // This bit works fine
    }
    addLiAnchorNodes();
});
```

Comment: why on earth would you do `var foo = $(X)` to convert X into a jQuery object and then add `foo.html()` to the text when you can just do `tmp += X` ?

Comment: @Alnitak : i absolutely agree with you. Thanks. i have updated my code.

Comment: Thanks guys, so good to see different ways to achieve the result. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Instead of appending the list item in each loop, append the list only once at the end.

```
$(function(){
    var peekList = $('<ul class="peekaboo-list"></ul>');    
    peekList.appendTo('div.peekaboo-wrap');    
    var addLiAnchorNodes = function (nodeAmount){        
        var list = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            list += '<li><a href="#" class="peekaboo-link">Sample</a><p class="peekaboo-text"></p></li>';            
        }
        peekList.append(list);
    }
    addLiAnchorNodes();
});
```

Here is the updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hEjxP/19/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var peekList = $('<ul class="peekaboo-list"></ul>');


    $(peekList).appendTo('div.peekaboo-wrap'); // This bit works fine

    var addLiAnchorNodes = function (nodeAmount){
        //var nodeAmount = peekListAmount;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            var peekListItem = $('<li><a href="#" class="peekaboo-link"></a><p class="peekaboo-text"></p></li>');
            peekListItem.appendTo(peekList);
        }

    }
    addLiAnchorNodes();
});
```

Comment: more thanks - I'm going to take all of these and have a good look

Comment: and everyone who answered - I'm going to accept all answers here as I'm going to work with them all: I'll look at the differences, absorb, and will do speed tests to see which one is fastest/most economical.
Thanks again